# How to combine $(document) and $(window.parent.document) into one?

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors

In case of an <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, I am closing an overlay in an iFrame.

I need to listen that keydown both in the frame and in the parent.

My current code goes like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        console.log('ESCAPE 1');
    }
});
$(window.parent.document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        console.log('ESCAPE 2');
    }
});
```

As you see, the only difference is the selector part.

My question is, can I make that code shorter?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) :

```
$(document).add(window.parent.document).keydown(...
```

Comment: what is `window.parent.document`.? can you link me to the relevant article..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy it's the document of the parent window (look at the question)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy What's wrong with 'your' google??? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent